# how to configure local built php as CGI through .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have no root priority, so i cannot the system level PHP environment, so i build a php installation to my home directory, that is /home/meow/build/

then i add the following lines to .htaccess:

```
AddHandler php-handler .php
Action php-handler "/home/meow/doaminname/cgi-bin"
```

that cgi-bin is in fact a script, the contents in it is:

```
    exec "/home/meow/build/bin/php-cgi" $@
```

when i try to visit domainname/a.php, the error message is:

```
The requested URL /home/meow/cgi-bin/p.php was not found on this server
```

what's wront?

Comment: From the error it tells that cgi-bin should have been a folder and that the p.php is not inside of it. And it should be at `/home/meow/cgi-bin/p.php` and not `/home/meow/doaminname/cgi-bin`

Answer (score 1):

The `Action` directive wants [a URL-path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#action), not a file-path. That means your `cgi-bin` needs to be inside your site's document root, and the `Action` directive points to it via a path relative to the document root.

Without knowing how you have your document root setup, I'm going to guess you want something like:

```
Action php-handler "/cgi-bin"
```

That being you can access the same script via `http://yourdomain.com/cgi-bin`.